# BAM Server is unavailable

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-bam

I am trying to access BAM server but the following error is thrown:

```
"The BAM Server is unavailable. 
The server may have been started or restarted recently. 
Try logging in again after the startup completes. 
If the problem persists, contact your System Administrator. "
```

I checked the BAM Web Properties in Enterprise Manager and it is pointing to correct Application URL and Server name.

I also checked the Application Console and it shows that the BAM server is up and running (with OK Health status).

On checking the logs found that the BAM Active Data Cache was not starting properly. 
Any pointers on what could be the reason for ADC not starting correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem and one restart solved my problem, sometimes BAM doesn't start properly.

Comment: This is at best a workaround, not a solution to the underlying problem.